# window.location is not woking

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I'm using jQuery with Django in server-side. What I'm trying to do is to get some text from the user through the form and simultaneously displaying the text in the canvas area like about.me and flavors.me does. Then the user drag the text in the canvas area to the desired position and when they click the next button,the data must be stored in the database and redirect to the homepage. Everything is working perfect(the datas are stored in the database) except when I click the button which I set window.location to `"http://127.0.0.1:8000".` But I'm not getting to that page when I click the button.

I'm getting some errors in Django server:

```
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 51161)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
```

Here is my html:
https://gist.github.com/2359541

Django views.py:

from cover.models import CoverModel
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

```
def coverview(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
            t = request.POST.get('top')
            l = request.POST.get('left')
            n = request.POST.get('name')
            h = request.POST.get('headline')
            try:
                    g = CoverModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
            except CoverModel.DoesNotExist:
                    co = CoverModel(top=t, left=l, name=n, headline=h)
                    co.user = request.user
                    co.save()
            else:
                    g.top = t
                    g.left = l
                    g.name = n
                    g.headline = h
                    g.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^cover/check/$', 'cover.views.coverview'),
url(r'^cover/$', login_required(direct_to_template), {'template': 'cover.html'}),
```

Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably a problem on the server side, i.e. with your Python code.

Comment: You should remove the HttpResponseRedirect('/') from the python side. No need to redirect there as well. Just return HttpResponse('loaded') or something like that.

Comment: @Jordan I changed it but getting the same error "Broken Pipe". Between  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's really not enough information in your question to properly diagnose this, but you can try this:

It's *always* a bad idea to hard-code a domain name in your JS. What happens when you take this to production, for example? If you want to send the user to the homepage (presumed from the location being set to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`), then set the location simply to `/`. That will ensure that it will always go to the site root regardless of the IP address, domain name or port.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that you're trying to post data, and then immediately leaving the page by using window.location. You should only change the window.location whenever you get the response back from the $.post().

```
$.post("check/", { top: t, left: l, name: n, headline: h}, function(data) {
    window.location.href = "/";
});
```

Notice also that I removed the hardcoded URL. Use a relative one here, like Chris said.

If it still isn't working, you need to check for Javascript errors in the lines above. Use Firebug, Chrome Dev Tools, Opera Dragonfly, something. Check to make sure your POST is actually going through, and post more data about that back here.

Comment: Still not working. I'm sure post is working because I'm getting the datas in the server side. I updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: I'm redirecting to the same page. So I can't see the errors in Chrome browser.

Comment: Wait, so if you're redirecting, does that mean it's working? I thought your question was about how it's not redirecting.

Comment: I want to redirect to the homepage which is the localhost http://127.0.0.1:8000/ But here I'm redirecting to the same page http://127.0.0.1:8000/cover/ If you need anymore details I can give you.

Comment: Using the code I posted would redirect you to the homepage. Can you update your gist or question with what you currently have that's still not working?